# How to calculate the displayed width of content in the table cell?

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate the width of the content in the table cell,if the content length is larger than the cell width,then substring the content and add `...` in the end

Dose Anyone know how to calculate?

No`string.length`,No`css`,just`javacript`

Comment: Better use [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

Comment: @Andy Because,String.length is not exatly the really width in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question,hope this could help

```
String.prototype.width = function (fontSize) {
    var el,
    f = fontSize + " px arial" || '12px arial';
    el = document.createElement('div');
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    el.style.float = "left";
    el.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    el.style.font = f;
    el.innerHTML = this;
    el = document.body.appendChild(el);
    w = el.offsetWidth;
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    return w;
}
// Usage  
"MyString".width(12);
```